# Paypal Sandbox - Invalid Merchant Configuration error 10501?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to do a `DoDirectPayment` with the Sandbox API

I have been testing with code that I know works but my API credentials are getting the following error back from the Sandbox API

**[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10501 

    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid Configuration

[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration**

After looking up the error code I found that the problem "*Occurs when the billing agreement is disabled or inactive.*"

I have searched Google intensively for how to Agree to the Billing Agreement in the sandbox but to no prevail

Has anyone had this issue and know how to switch it on?

Comment: you got any proper solution for this please shares with me below solution is not working for me. still, i am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 56):

Like the the other answers say, you need to to enable Payments Pro in your sandbox account. As of July 2013, you can do this with the steps below.

1. Login to your developer.paypal.com account
2. Go to Applications -> Sandbox Accounts
3. Click the sandbox account you want to upgrade to Pro, and then click 'profile'
4. There should be an Upgrade to Pro option in the dialog that pops up

Note the paypal developer website has been changing quite a bit recently, so your mileage may vary...

Comment: Have tried to "Upgrade to Pro" multiple times now but I always get "Sorry, something went wrong.Please try again later.".

Comment: I'm getting same error as @PeterAndersson reported  "Sorry, something went wrong.Please try again later."

Comment: wish that i woulda seen this sooner. found it out the hard way after searching the logged in profile for the "billing agreement" for 30 min.

Comment: They now say enable "Direct credit cards": https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/account/status

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I've spent almost a day looking for a solution.

Comment: Thanks ..but still i am facing the same problem as i have enabled that.what is the issue now

Comment: I have a business pro sandbox account. It worked fine for 1st two payments, later it  gives 10501 error.

Answer (score 9):

It means your sandbox test account is not set up for Payments Pro.
Go to https://developer.paypal.com > Test accounts > preconfigured and create a preconfigured US Website Payments Pro test account.

Comment: The sandbox environment currently has a bug which prevents the creation of preconfigured Payments Pro accounts I'm afraid. This will be resolved as soon as possible.

Comment: Same problem here. Tried today and it's giving me the same error

Comment: This should be resolved today for new accounts going forward.

Comment: Hi Robert, the "Sorry, something went wrong.  Please try again later."   error is occurring again when trying to upgrade a sandbox business account to Pro.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

There was recently a redesign of the developer site.

I don't know about existing accounts, but for new accounts you cannot use the default "facilitator" sandbox test account for testing the classic api ... you have to make a new business sandbox test account and use the credentials from that.  This is true even though the "facilitator" account is a business account.

The sandbox accounts are created in [https://developer.paypal.com/](https://developer.paypal.com) -> Applications -> Sandbox accounts (link on left side) -> Create Account (button on right side)

Comment: I just ran into this. The facilitator account doesn't have the option to Upgrade to Pro. You can't even delete that account either.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same issue and wrote paypal about it, this was their response:

Thank you for contacting Merchant Technical Services.

Regarding to your issue with an error invalid merchant configuration, this error happened because of your sandbox account still in pending status. It happened when you changed from business to pro. This is bug in our system and kindly our engineer still in progress in fixing this bugs. By the way, you can try create new sandbox account and then upgrade to pro account as what you did before this.

Comment: I contacted them further and basically their response is "it's broken, no ETA on fixing it, use a LIVE account for testing"

Comment: I am beginning to lose count how many times I have had paypal tell me the same thing. It's quite ridiculous.

Comment: Still it is the same issue, we have to create new account every day to test on sandbox.